# Python dict/list mix is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I'm a bit stumped.  I'm trying to build JSON string, and it's generating a traceback in my program.  The really odd thing, is that if I cut and paste into a console, the whole thing works.

First, here's the code.

```
    def readgs2JSON(self, msg):
    d = {"Channel" : "Readings"}
    d["Sensor"] = msg.ReadingsChn.ReadingReport.attrib["Sensor"]
    d["ReadingID"] = msg.ReadingsChn.ReadingReport.attrib["ReadingID"]
    d["Detect"] = msg.ReadingsChn.ReadingReport.Data.attrib["Detect"]
    d["Level"] = msg.ReadingsChn.ReadingReport.Data.attrib["Level"]
    d["Units"] = msg.ReadingsChn.ReadingReport.Data.attrib["Units"]
    if "Id" in msg.ReadingsChn.ReadingReport.Data.attrib:
        d["Id"] = msg.ReadingsChn.ReadingReport.Data.attrib["Id"]
    d["SUD"] = [el.attrib for el in msg.ReadingsChn.ReadingReport.Data.iterchildren()]
    print d
    return d
```

The variable msg is an objectified element produced by lxml.  The dictionary, d generated by the code looks like this when you print it. (Sorry that's hard to read.  It doesn't seem to want to line wrap nicely.)

```
{'Detect': 'NONE', 'Level': '0', 'SUD': [{'Type': 'int', 'Name':'Reading1', 'Value': '75856'}, {'Type': 'int', 'Name': 'Reading2', 'Value': '75857'}, {'Type': 'int', 'Name': 'Reading3', 'Value': '75858'}, {'Type': 'int', 'Name': 'Reading4', 'Value': '75859'}, {'Type': 'int', 'Name': 'ClockTicks', 'Value': '389'}, {'Type': 'array', 'Name': 'Spectrum', 'Value': 'None'}], 'Units': 'bars', 'ReadingID': 'R000009233', 'Sensor': 'SC001', 'Channel': 'Readings'}
```

So, when I execute **json.dumps(d)** inside my program, I get a traceback:

```
[Failure instance: Traceback: <type 'exceptions.TypeError'>: {'Type':   'int', 'Name': 'Reading1', 'Value': '75856'} is not JSON serializable
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py:1195:run
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/base.py:1204:mainLoop
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet 
/base.py:825:runUntilCurrent
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet/task.py:239:__call__
--- <exception caught here> ---
/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/twisted/internet
/defer.py:149:maybeDeferred
/home/max/workspace/canary/CCSIEventHandler.py:26:tick
/home/max/workspace/canary/CCSIEventHandler.py:99:event2Msg
/home/max/workspace/canary/sensorcache.py:715:writeToBuffer
/home/max/workspace/canary/CCSI2JSON.py:37:pushCCSIMessage
/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/__init__.py:244:dumps
/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py:207:encode
/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py:270:iterencode
/usr/lib64/python2.7/json/encoder.py:184:default
]
```

So, the really odd thing, is if I copy the printed dict from my terminal, and past it into a python console, then the whole thing works!

```
>>> json.dumps(d)
'{"SUD": [{"Type": "int", "Name": "Reading1", "Value": "75856"}, {"Type": "int", "Name": "Reading2", "Value": "75857"}, {"Type": "int", "Name": "Reading3", "Value": "75858"}, {"Type": "int", "Name": "Reading4", "Value": "75859"}, {"Type": "int", "Name": "ClockTicks", "Value": "389"}, {"Type": "array", "Name": "Spectrum", "Value": "None"}], "Level": "0", "Detect": "NONE", "Units": "bars", "ReadingID": "R000009233", "Sensor": "SC001", "Channel": "Readings"}'
```

For the life of me, I can't spot the difference, but I'm no JSON expert.  Has anyone else had this problem?

Turns out I was trying to serialize an lxml.etree._Attrib, which I thought was a dictionary, as it works like a dict.  Here's the adjusted code that builds a dictionary, and works correctly.

```
    def readgs2JSON(self, msg):
    d = {"Channel" : "Readings"}
    d["Sensor"] = msg.ReadingsChn.ReadingReport.attrib["Sensor"]
    d["ReadingID"] = msg.ReadingsChn.ReadingReport.attrib["ReadingID"]
    d["Detect"] = msg.ReadingsChn.ReadingReport.Data.attrib["Detect"]
    d["Level"] = msg.ReadingsChn.ReadingReport.Data.attrib["Level"]
    d["Units"] = msg.ReadingsChn.ReadingReport.Data.attrib["Units"]
    if "Id" in msg.ReadingsChn.ReadingReport.Data.attrib:
        d["Id"] = msg.ReadingsChn.ReadingReport.Data.attrib["Id"]
    sud_list = []
    for el in msg.ReadingsChn.ReadingReport.Data.iterchildren():
        sud_dict = {}
        for item in el.attrib:
            sud_dict[item] = el.attrib[item]
        sud_list.append(sud_dict)
    if sud_list is not []:
        d["SUD"] = sud_list
    return d
```

Comment: Children of `msg.ReadingsChn.ReadingReport.Data` are of some special type, and they are not JSON serializable. The reason it is printed to the console correctly is because that type has overridden `__str__` or `__repr__`.

Comment: Try `print type(d["SUD"][0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Children of `msg.ReadingsChn.ReadingReport.Data` are of some special type, and they are not `JSON` serializable. The reason it is printed to the console correctly is because that type has overridden `__str__` or `__repr__`.

Comment: Sure enough, d["SUD"][0] is <type 'lxml.etree._Attrib'> !